I am geting Cycle errors from trying to create security groups on terraform
I am getting a cycle error from my terraform code when trying to create security groups. Initially, the security groups referenced each other, but for debugging purposes, I removed the references. However, the error persists.
this is the error:
Error: Cycle: aws_security_group.security_groups["SSH-Security-Group"], aws_security_group.security_groups["Backend-Security-Group"], aws_security_group.security_groups["Frontend-Security-Group"], aws_security_group.security_groups["Frontend-ALB-Security-Group"], aws_security_group.security_groups["Database-Security-Group"], aws_security_group.security_groups["Backend-NLB-Security-Group"]

the resource definition:
variable "security_groups" {}

locals {
  vpc_id = {
    tersu = data.aws_vpc.tersu
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "security_groups" {
  for_each = var.security_groups

  name        = each.value.name
  description = each.value.description
  vpc_id      = local.vpc_id[each.value.vpc].id

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = each.value.ingress
    content {
      description     = ingress.value.description
      from_port       = ingress.value.from_port
      to_port         = ingress.value.to_port
      protocol        = ingress.value.protocol
      cidr_blocks     = lookup(ingress.value, "cidr_blocks", null) != null ? ingress.value.cidr_blocks : null
      security_groups = lookup(ingress.value, "security_groups", null) != null ? [for sg in ingress.value.security_groups : aws_security_group.security_groups[sg].id] : null
    }
  }

  dynamic "egress" {
    for_each = each.value.egress
    content {
      description     = egress.value.description
      from_port       = egress.value.from_port
      to_port         = egress.value.to_port
      protocol        = egress.value.protocol
      cidr_blocks     = lookup(egress.value, "cidr_blocks", null) != null ? egress.value.cidr_blocks : null
      security_groups = lookup(egress.value, "security_groups", null) != null ? [for sg in egress.value.security_groups : aws_security_group.security_groups[sg].id] : null
    }
  }

  tags = merge(each.value.tags, local.tags)
}

the values in the values file:
security_groups = {
  "Frontend-ALB-Security-Group" = {
    name        = "Frontend-ALB-Security-Group"
    description = "Enable http/https access on port 80/443"
    vpc         = "tersu"
    ingress = [
      {
        description = "http access"
        from_port   = 80
        to_port     = 80
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      },
      {
        description = "https access"
        from_port   = 443
        to_port     = 443
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    ]
    egress = [
      {
        from_port   = 0
        to_port     = 0
        protocol    = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    ]
    tags = {
      Name = "Frontend-ALB-Security-Group"
    }
  }

  "Backend-NLB-Security-Group" = {
    name        = "Backend-NLB-Security-Group"
    description = "Enable http/https access on port 5000"
    vpc         = "tersu"
    ingress = [
      {
        description     = "Backend access from frontend"
        from_port       = 5000
        to_port         = 5000
        protocol        = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    ]
    egress = [
      {
        from_port   = 0
        to_port     = 0
        protocol    = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    ]
    tags = {
      Name = "Backend-ALB-Security-Group"
    }
  },

  "Frontend-Security-Group" = {
    name        = "Frontend-Security-Group"
    description = "Enable http, https, and ssh access on ports 80, 443, and 22 respectively"
    vpc         = "tersu"
    ingress = [
      {
        description = "HTTP access"
        from_port   = 80
        to_port     = 80
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      },
      {
        description = "HTTPS access"
        from_port   = 443
        to_port     = 443
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      },
      {
        description = "ssh access"
        from_port   = 22
        to_port     = 22
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    ]
    egress = [
      {
        description     = "Allow outbound traffic to backend"
        from_port       = 5000
        to_port         = 5000
        protocol        = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    ]
    tags = {
      Name = "Frontend-Security-Group"
    }
  }

  "Backend-Security-Group" = {
    name        = "Backend-Security-Group"
    description = "Enable http, https, on port 5000 for ingress, and 5432 for egress respectively"
    vpc         = "tersu"
    ingress = [
      {
        description     = "Allow inbound traffic from frontend"
        from_port       = 5000
        to_port         = 5000
        protocol        = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    ]
    egress = [
      {
        description     = "Allow outbound traffic to database"
        from_port       = 5432
        to_port         = 5432
        protocol        = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    ]
    tags = {
      Name = "Backend-Security-Group"
    }
  }

  "Database-Security-Group" = {
    name        = "Database-Security-Group"
    description = "Enable Postgresql access on port 5432"
    vpc         = "tersu"
    ingress = [
      {
        description     = "https access"
        from_port       = 5432
        to_port         = 5432
        protocol        = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    ]

    egress = [
      {
        from_port   = 0
        to_port     = 0
        protocol    = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    ]

    tags = {
      Name = "Database-Security-Group"
    }
  }

  "SSH-Security-Group" = {
    name        = "SSH-Security-Group"
    description = "Enable SSH access on port 22"
    vpc         = "tersu"

    ingress = [
      {
        description = "ssh access"
        from_port   = 22
        to_port     = 22
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    ]

    egress = [
      {
        from_port   = 0
        to_port     = 0
        protocol    = "-1"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      }
    ]

    tags = {
      Name = "SSH-Security-Group"
    }
  }
}

I am not sure what the error could be because even when I leave only one value for the security groups, I get a self-reference error.
Please what could be the issue?

The reference is still there: aws_security_group.security_groups[sg].id. It is in the lookup function. What I would advise is to use the aws_security_group_rule resource instead of adding ingress/egress rules in-line with the aws_security_group resource.

@marko-e your solution worked. separating them using aws_security_group_rules fixed the issue.

I want to start that in your input data you do not have any  security_groups in ingress or egress maybe you do not need those lines of code:
security_groups = lookup(ingress.value, "security_groups", null) ...
it could be as simple as removing those lines.
Also your code has issues with description, that is missing in some of the egress values you provided, maybe add another lookup there with a proper default.

option 1
to break the dependency cycle you could use aws_security_group_rule:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule
is important to point out that source_security_group_id only allows one item
we will have to collect all the rules (ingress and egress) in one variable to later loop over
sample code below
locals {
  vpc_id = {
    tersu = data.aws_vpc.v
  }
  all_rules = [[
    for sg in var.security_groups : [
      for i, ingress in sg.ingress :
        merge({ "name" : sg.name, "type" : "ingress", "index": i }, ingress)
    ]
   ],[
    for index, sg in var.security_groups : [
      for i, egress in sg.egress :
        merge({ "name" : sg.name, "type" : "egress", "index": i }, egress)
    ]
  ]]
  rules = {
    for x in flatten(local.all_rules): "${x.name}_${x.type}_${x.index}" => x
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg" {
  for_each = var.security_groups
  name     = each.value.name
  vpc_id   = local.vpc_id[each.value.vpc].id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "rule" {
  for_each          = local.rules
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.sg[each.value.name].id

  type              = each.value.type
  from_port         = each.value.from_port
  to_port           = each.value.to_port
  protocol          = each.value.protocol
  cidr_blocks       = lookup(each.value, "cidr_blocks", null)

  source_security_group_id = lookup(each.value, "security_groups", null) == null ? null : (
    aws_security_group.sg[each.value.security_groups].id
  )
}



option 2
According to the documentation:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group#ingress
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group#egress


security_groups - (Optional) List of security groups. A group name can be used relative to the default VPC. Otherwise, group ID.

Since the group name can be used, I would use that instead of the ID, in your values the name is the same as the key so we can quickly retrieve those with keys(var.security_groups) no more loops referencing back to the same resource, that was the cause of your Cycle errors
Here is something you can do:
locals {
  vpc_id = {
    tersu = data.aws_vpc.v
  }
  security_groups = keys(var.security_groups)
}

resource "aws_security_group" "security_groups" {
  for_each = var.security_groups

  name        = each.value.name
  vpc_id      = local.vpc_id[each.value.vpc].id

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = each.value.ingress
    content {
      from_port       = ingress.value.from_port
      to_port         = ingress.value.to_port
      protocol        = ingress.value.protocol
      cidr_blocks     = lookup(ingress.value, "cidr_blocks", null)
      security_groups = lookup(ingress.value, "security_groups", null) != null ? local.security_groups : null
    }
  }

  dynamic "egress" {
    for_each = each.value.egress
    content {
      from_port       = egress.value.from_port
      to_port         = egress.value.to_port
      protocol        = egress.value.protocol
      cidr_blocks     = lookup(egress.value, "cidr_blocks", null)
      security_groups = lookup(egress.value, "security_groups", null) != null ? local.security_groups : null
    }
  }
}

